# What am I doing wrong here with the selection sort. Keeps giving me issues about the type

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class SortingforFun {
    static final String IN_FILE = "sorting.txt";
    static final int ARRAY_SIZE = 20000;

    public static void  main(String[] arg) {

        long[] arr1= new long [ARRAY_SIZE];


        long[] arr2 = (long[])arr1.clone();



        long startTime = System.startHere();



        int i;

        System.out.println("\n\n RoseIndia\n\n");
        System.out.println(" Selection Sort\n\n");
        System.out.println("Values Before the sort:\n");
        for(i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++)
        System.out.print( arr1[i]+"  ");
        System.out.println();
        selection_srt(ARRAY_SIZE, arr1.length);
        System.out.print("Values after the sort:\n");
        for(i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++)
        System.out.print(arr1[i]+"  ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("PAUSE");
    }

    public static void selection_srt(long ARRAY_SIZE , long n){
        for(long x=0; x<n; x++){
            long index_of_min = x;
            for(long y=x; y<n; y++){
                if(ARRAY_SIZE[(index_of_min]< ARRAY_SIZE[y]){
                    index_of_min = y;
                }
            }
            long temp = ARRAY_SIZE[x];
            ARRAY_SIZE[x] = ARRAY_SIZE[index_of_min];
            ARRAY_SIZE[index_of_min] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What issue? What is the error? Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: what is System.startHere(). This is in addition of what @Dave Costa said.

Answer (score 3):

In the `selection_sort` method, you are getting a parameter `ARRAY_SIZE` of type `long`, and trying to use it as an array.  I presume that's what's causing the type warning you reference (although it would be clearer if you showed the specific error message you got).

I am guessing that you want that method to have a signature like:

```
public static void selection_srt( long[] array, long n )
```

and pass `arr1` or `arr2` when you're calling it.

You haven't put any actually data into those arrays either, although that will not cause an error.  All the elements will be initialized to 0 automatically, so sorting them won't be very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

using the long `ARRAY_SIZE` with square brackets `[]` as if it were an array is already a mistake. I don't think your code compiles

Also, you have a name shadowing problem - the parameter ARRAY_SIZE (of type long) is shadowing the static member with the same name, albeit of type int.